# How to re-cast a java array

Tags: java, arrays

So i'm trying to read some user input which is then checked against two arrays of strings, then if the user input equals something in either of the arrays i want to put the user input into a new array, but when i go to print the new array which should contain the user input it prints that every value in the array is null

```
    String[] VegiFruit = {"Apples", "Lettuce", "Broccoli"};
    String[] Meats = {"Ground beef", "Hambuger"};
    String[] Input = new String[20];
    String[] InputGreen = new String[20];
    String done = "done";
    Scanner USER_IN = new Scanner(System.in);
    Methods Use = new Methods();    //This is another class I have that just makes printing blank lines and borders look nicer

    Use.border();
    System.out.println("Enter Item name then follow instructions.");
    Use.space();

    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i+": ");
        Input[i] = USER_IN.nextLine();
        if(Arrays.asList(VegiFruit).contains(Input))
        {
            InputGreen[i] = Input[i];
            System.out.println(InputGreen[i]); //Prints null for every value
        }
    }
```

So am I doing something wrong with the logic? or is it something else?

Comment: That's not the way how a scanner use.

Comment: When I read your code I got very confused at first - I would highly recommend conforming to standard naming conventions in Java. For example, userIn, inputGreen, isGreen, meats, input, etc...

Comment: I believe `.contains(Input)` should be `.contains(Input[i])`.

Comment: Your .contains should have an index. Eg. .contains(Arrays.asList(VegiFruit).contains(Input[i]).

Comment: And `IsGreen[i] = true;` should give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `IsGreen.length` is always zero.

Comment: You should also be getting  an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when i = = 20, seeing as your array only has 20 elements (which are index from 0 to 19).

Comment: Also consider just using List<Integer>, eg. List<String> vegiFruit = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Apples", "Lettuce", "Broccoli"});. What if your user enters apple? or apples?

Comment: @Siguza thanks, guess I didn't look too hard at my if statement

Comment: How do you expect IsGrean to work? Is that supposed to involve user input? Also sooo many arrays, they made classes for a reason.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with its title?

Comment: @matt I forget where i was going with the booleans, got rid of them, also I believe the new title should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Arrays.asList(VegiFruit).contains(Input))
```

This line is totally wrong because you are comparing the object(Here Input is an parameter value of .contains method, it is an object) with a List of element, here element of the list is a String value.

So change the code like below,

```
if (Arrays.asList(VegiFruit).contains(Input[i])) {
    InputGreen[i] = Input[i];
    System.out.println(InputGreen[i]); //Now it is print the corresponding value.
}
```